# Issue rendering the selected cell on a QTableView

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a custom `QTableView` and a custom `QAbstractTableModel`. The view only allows single selections. I'm trying to customize the background color of the selected cell under some conditions with no success. I expected to do it by combining the `data` method of the model with the `selectionChanged` method of the view. For instance, let's suppose I want to change the color of the selected cell when it matches a given row. My code for the `selectionChanged` method is:

```
def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
    #QtGui.QTableView.selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected)
    # Get the selected indexes from the QItemSelection object
    selection = selected.indexes()
    # Let the model track the selected cell
    self.tmodel.selected_index = selection[0]
    # Desperately try to make it work
    self.tmodel.dataChanged.emit(selection[0], selection[0])
    self.viewport().update()
```

My simplified code for the `data` method is:

```
def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    # Some code here dealing with several roles
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
    ...
    elif role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if ((index == self.selected_index) and (index.row() == 3)):
            print '++++ displaying selected'
            return QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.yellow)
        else:
            return QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green)
    else:
        return None
```

The non selected cells have a green background as expected. The strange thing is that when I select a cell in the matching row, the message `++++ displaying selected` is printed but the selected cell has the system default background instead of a yellow one. I must be missing something important/obvious here but I've no idea about what it is.

**Update**

I know I can achieve my goal using a custom delegate and implementing its `paint` method but I'd like to know why the code above fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I got it. The think is that the default delegate uses the values returned by `data` in order to render the table cells. Accordingly to the [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/model-view-programming.html):

> By supplying appropriate item data for each role, models can provide
>   hints to views and delegates about how items should be presented to
>   the user. Different kinds of views have the freedom to interpret or
>   ignore this information as required.

So the behavior described in the question is explained as follow: non selected cells are rendered in the standard way by the default delegate which implies the color returned by `data` method will be used. However, selected cell are rendered in a different way by the default delegate, the value returned by `data` method is ignored in this case because it uses the background provided by the system style.